# How do I fix my program? Counting articles in an input file

Tags: string, file, input, counting

I need to count the articles (a, an, and, the) in a input file. Below is the code I wrote. It counts the articles, but it also counts the letters or strings of letters in the word, for example, the word "sand", or the word "thanks" would be counted as an article. How can I adjust my code?

```
def countArticles (line):
    articleCount = 0
    for art in line:
        if art ==" a " or art ==" A " or art == " An " or art ==" an " or art ==" and " or art == "And "  or art ==" the " or art ==" The ":
            articleCount = articleCount + 1
    return articleCount
```

Comment: Have you tried more complex string comparison such as Regular Expression (RegEx)? There are many site to help you learn about RegEx; for example, https://regex101.com/ , https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might attempt this with something like this:

```
def countArticles (line):
    articleCount = 0
    for art in line.lower().split(' '): # Make the words all lowercase, split on spaces.
        if art in ("a", "an", "and", "the"):
            articleCount = articleCount + 1
    return articleCount
```

Comment: That's wonderful! Can you accept it as the answer? (and maybe give me an upvote?)